# Logger not showing in ASP.NET Core 2.1 Application

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

As the title says, why my Logger not showing in the console when I run the application with `dotnet run`

I'm using the Logger in class other than Controller though.

Here's the code:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestService service;
    public TestController(ITestService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public TestService(ILogger<TestService> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Task SomeFunction()
    {
        logger.Information("Do some function");
        return Task.CompleteTask;
    }
}
```

I'm using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` for the ILogger

Here's how I register my service in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<ITestService>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithTransientLifetime());
```

I'm using `Scrutor` for the `Scan`

And here's my configuration for my `Program.cs`:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.MachineName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

As the code, I tried to call logger with `logger.Information("");` and the logger didn't show in my console.

What's wrong with my code?

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance

Edit:

Almost forget, here's my `appsettings.json` :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": "true"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: For `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, there is no `Information`, it has `LogInformation`, and `Task.CompleteTask` should be `Task.CompletedTask`. I fail to reproduce your issue with [LoggingCore](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/LoggingCore). Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding using logging in any component:

You just missed AddTransient.

Here's full example which worked for me.

> Adding logging to a component in your application is done by requesting either an `ILoggerFactory` or an `ILogger<T>` via Dependency Injection. If an `ILoggerFactory` is requested, a logger must be created using its `CreateLogger` method.

If your `CustomClass` is a data container (DTO class), it should not know about logging, but just contain data.

For other classes with names like "Service" , "Provider", "Handler" and so on, the best practices is to resolve instances using dependency injection. In general, you should use DI wherever it is possible, as it’s a technique for achieving loose coupling between objects and their collaborators or dependencies. For more information, the following question might be interesting: [Should I use Dependency Injection or static factories?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190120/should-i-use-dependency-injection-or-static-factories)

So simply add `ILogger<CustomClass>` to its constructor (actually the same way, as you do for controllers), as .NET Core supports only constructor injection by default:

```
public class CustomClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CustomClass(ILogger<CustomClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

---

ASP.NET Core’s built-in dependency injection container will automatically resolved transient dependencies. So if your controller has class `A` as a dependency that uses class `B` where you want to log something, your code can be something like this:

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(ClassA classA)
    { ... }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(ClassB classB)
    { ... }
}

public class ClassB
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ClassB(ILogger<ClassB> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithLogging()
    {
        // use _logger
    }
}
```

Note that you also need to register the dependencies in `Startup` using `IServiceCollection.Add…` methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddTransient<ClassB>();
    services.AddTransient<ClassA>();
}
```

---

Built-in logging support means that .NET Core out of the box knows about and is using built-in abstractions for logging. This is mainly done by  `ILoggerFactory` and  `ILoggerProvider` interfaces.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a type used to configure the logging system and create instances of <see cref="ILogger"/> from
/// the registered <see cref="ILoggerProvider"/>s.
/// </summary>
public interface ILoggerFactory : IDisposable

// <summary>
/// Represents a type that can create instances of <see cref="ILogger"/>.
/// </summary>
public interface ILoggerProvider : IDisposable
```

Using your own `ILoggerProvider` implementation, you can add your own logger that can do whatever you want. You can check the [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.Logging/NLogLoggerProvider.cs) logger implementation as working example.

And thanks to `ILoggerFactory`, you can simply configure your Logger for project-specific purposes:

> To configure logging in your ASP.NET Core application, you should resolve `ILoggerFactory` in the `Configure` method of your `Startup` class. ASP.NET Core will automatically provide an instance of `ILoggerFactory` using Dependency Injection when you add a parameter of this type to the `Configure` method.

Comment: I'm not really understand about DI. So I need to register the class using `ServiceCollection`? Can I register it using `Scrutor` just like my registration for my service?

Comment: @itssolutionnow, Your answer is not the questioner asking for. I have found  nothing wrong in the questioner code. He is asking why it is not showing in the console?

Comment: @TanvirArjel, I just wanted to say that he just forgotten this.

services.AddTransient<ClassB>();